# Multimarkers in a bing Map

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am having a problem in putting a marker for every location in my bing map, this is my code:

```
private async void geolocator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    await
    // Need to get back onto UI thread before updating location information
    this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new DispatchedHandler(
    async () =>
    {
        UriString4 = "my URL";
        var http = new HttpClient();
        http.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
        var response = await http.GetStringAsync(UriString4);
        var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NvBarberry.Models.RootObject>(response);
        Location[] location = new Location[int.Parse(rootObject.total)];
        for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(rootObject.total); i++)
        {
            //Get the current location

            location[i] = new Location(rootObject.locals[i].local_latit,rootObject.locals[i].local_longi);

            //Update the position of the GPS pushpin
            MapLayer.SetPosition(GpsIcon, location[i]);

            //Set the radius of the Accuracy Circle
            GpsIcon.SetRadius(args.Position.Coordinate.Accuracy);

            //Make GPS pushpin visible
            GpsIcon.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;

            //Update the map view to the current GPS location
            MyMap.SetView(location[i], 17);

        }
    }));}
```

This is the JSON data from where I want to get the local_longi and
    local_latit of every Location:

```
{
    success : 1,
    total : 2,
    locals : [{
            id_local : "59",
            local_longi : "20",
            local_latit : "25894"
        }, {
            id_local : "60",
            local_longi : "10.33699",
            local_latit : "25.997745"
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is that I get only one marker on the map, which is the last Location from Longitude, Lattitude (according to tha JSON data I get on Map only the location with this values:

```
local_longi: "10.33699",
local_latit: "25.997745"
```

And this is what I get when debugging:
[image]

I get all results in "location" variable, why I get only one marker in the Map

this is the tutorial that I have followed:
https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2012/11/05/getting-started-with-bing-maps-windows-store-apps-native/

Update:
this is my xaml code for the Map:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <m:Map Name="MyMap" Credentials="1m8dxWklva2lte3kYjkn~........" ZoomLevel="13" />

        <CheckBox Content="GPS" Click="GPS_Checked"/>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey try to bind a OberservableCollection of Pushpin(Class from me).

```
<Maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Pushpins}">
                        <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Pushpin">
                                <StackPanel Maps:MapControl.Location="{x:Bind Location, Converter={StaticResource PointConverter}}"


Maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="{x:Bind Path='', Converter={StaticResource DefaultAnchorPointConverter}}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}"
                                           Foreground="Black" />
                                <Image Source="{x:Bind Path='', Converter={StaticResource PushpinConverter}}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </Maps:MapItemsControl>
```